# Why am I getting HTTP 500 error ONLY in private browsing mode (incognito)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

We are hosting a web application on AWS and the app is accessible in normal browsing mode.  Whenever you attempt to open the app in incognito (or whatever private is called in your client of choice) we get an HTTP 500.  I don't understand why that would be the case.  Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: can you try to clear your cookies and try again? I guess you will see the 500 error then. check your error logs to know what's the problem

Comment: I feel like it has something to do with your session cookie not being stored by the browser. Then your code relies on a session and throws an error/exception which would result in a 500 error if it was unhanded.

Comment: Maybe you are using some cookie that previously exists in the normal browsing mode. Try cleaning cookies in normal mode and check if the same error ocurrs

Comment: Presumably your webapp is returning the 500 response, so you should debug the webapp, using logs or whatever mechanism you would normally use to debug your webapp.